# How to store maxValue(column) using sqoop in oozie workflow?

Tags: sqoop, oozie

I am writing a oozie workflow to get data from postgresql to hdfs using sqoop.

I am able to get data to hdfs. But in my sqoop query i want a condition to get data from postgresql where id > max(id) (i.e the new query should get data from after the rows i have already processed from postgresql.)

To do so i was thinking of storing max(id) value from my current processed data. And then use this value as a parameter in my next query to filter already processed data. Can this method work?`<action name="RunSqoop">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
          <property>
            <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
            <value>${queueName}</value>
          </property>
        </configuration>
      <arg>import</arg>
      <arg>--append</arg>
      <arg>--connect</arg>
      <arg>jdbc:postgresql://10.smthng.smthng/arg>
      <arg>--password</arg>
      <arg>MyPass</arg>
      <arg>--username</arg>
      <arg>usr</arg>
      <arg>--query</arg>
      <arg>SELECT * from table where id>${maxid} </arg> //wana do smthng like this, But how to store this maxid
      <arg>--null-string</arg>
      <arg>\\N</arg>
      <arg>--fields-terminated-by</arg>
      <arg>\t</arg>
      <arg>-m</arg>
      <arg>1</arg>
      <arg>--target-dir</arg>
      <arg>/ds/ghds</arg>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="AlterTable"/>
    <error to="sendErrorEmail"/>
  </action>`

Is there any way i can store max value from a column being imported from postgresql using sqoop in oozie workflow? Please share how.

Comment: How do you expect to compute that MAX(ID) i.e. from PostGreSQL before running Sqoop ? from HDFS dump ? Then, what happens if some new ID is created while Sqoop is launching its parallel extracts (in different PostgreSQL sessions, in different transactions started at different times, with different versions of the truth) ?

Comment: I was thinking of getting data in hdfs and then in the same workflow I will run a new action to compute and store Max(ID). A hive script should be able to do this. What do you suggest?

Comment: Not sure about how extracting that "max" value. But if you can store it to HDFS somewhere, you may try something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521957/how-to-change-value-in-an-oozie-job-coordinator/31842842#31842842